# ¿Cuál es la diferencia? +FormularioPHP

Tags: php

La diferencia entre:

```
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
```

a)

---

```
isset($contraseña) ? print $contraseña : "";
```

b)

---

```
if(isset($contraseña))echo $contraseña . "";
```

Comment: En la doc. De PHP vienen explicados, ya revisaste algo al respecto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- En la primera linea:

```
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
```

Estas diciendo que la variable `$contraseña` es igual a lo que recibes como metodo `POST` de tu formulario

2.- En la segunda linea:

```
isset($contraseña) ? print $contraseña : "";
```

Estas utilizando un **operador ternario** donde el valor `true` se ejecuta despues de `?` y el `else` se ejecuta despues de `:` Basicamente en esa linea estas diciendo si esta definida la variable `$contraseña` "imprimela" de lo contrario imprime vacio.

3.- En la tercera linea es `if` tradicional

```
if(isset($contraseña))echo $contraseña . ""
```

Estas diciendo que si esta definida la variable contraseña la "imprimas" yo le agregaria el `else` para ser mas explicito quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
if(isset($contraseña)){echo $contraseña;} 
else{ echo "";}
```

Estarias diciendo si esta definida la variable `$contraseña` "imprimela" de lo contrario imprime "vacio";

Te dejo los siguientes enlaces que te ayudaran a comprender mejor:

[print Manual PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.print.php)

[echo Manual PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.echo.php)

[Operador ternario](https://riptutorial.com/es/php/example/7608/operador-ternario------)

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente es que lo siguiente esta utilizando un condicional ternario

```
a) isset($contraseña) ? print $contraseña : "";
```

Y lo otro, el if de siempre

```
b) if(isset($contraseña))echo $contraseña . "";
```

Un ejemplo practico seria lo siguiente

Usando el if-else:

```
$valor = true;
if ($valor) {
  echo 'El valor es verdadero'
}else {
  echo 'El valor es falso'
}
```

Usando condicional ternario:

```
$valor = true;
($valor)?echo 'El valor es verdadero':'El valor es falso';
```

Para mas informacion te recomiendo leer [Operadores de Comparacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php)